# Gaussian process regression implementaion

Tags: regression, matlab, gaussian-process

I am using the GPML matlab code [found here](https://gaussianprocess.org/gpml/code/matlab/doc/index.html). I have been using a squared exponential cov function with ARD. I am finding that if I use the minimise function to train the process I get uniform large vales for the output variance. I would expect the variance to be larger where there is no training values, however it is not. Could anyone give me an idea of where I might be going wrong?

I have included my code below:

```
clear all
close all
x=[14;21;18;23;24;22;16;16;16;9;10;7;12;18;31;12;10;5];
y=[18;22;29;24;22;20;18;17;12;8;6;7;15;17;28;16;5;5];

z = linspace(0, 40, 101)';

meanfunc = {@meanSum, {@meanLinear, @meanConst}};
covfunc =  @covSEard;
likfunc=@likGauss;
hyp2.cov = [1;0.1];
hyp2.lik = log(0.1);
hyp2.mean=[1;0.5];


hyp2 = minimize(hyp2, @gp, -100, @infExact, meanfunc, covfunc, likfunc, x, y);

nlml2 = gp(hyp2, @infExact, meanfunc, covfunc, likfunc, x, y);

[m s2] = gp(hyp2, @infExact, meanfunc, covfunc, likfunc, x, y, z);
f = [m+2*sqrt(s2); flipdim(m-2*sqrt(s2),1)];
fill([z; flipdim(z,1)], f, [7 7 7]/8)
hold on; plot(z, m); %plot(x, y, '+')
  
scatplot(x,y,'circles',1,[],[],1,[]);
```

I have also included the plots:
Firstly with the minimise function being used to optimise hyperparameters
[image]

And secondly without the minimise function being used:

[image]

Comment: the marginal likelihood surface is nonconvex; try a grid of initializations and you will likely find a nondegenerate hyperparameter configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the hyper-parameters after using minimise function?

You might notice that your regression line with minimising nlml is roughly linear, so i guess you simply fall into a crazy local minimum on hyperparameter.

Beside I can't see the point of using ARD cov function since your x is one dimensional.